# Firefox driver is not getting launch on VM machine

Tags: selenium, jenkins, virtual-machine, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
    1. resources I used : C# , Selenium , VS 2017, Jenkins , VM machine (windows 10) , Nunit v3.9, geckoDrive v19, firefox v56/57 

    2. I can execute firefox / chrome browser cases on local machine 

    3. I can execute chrome browser cases on VM machine 

    4. Issue : **I can Not execute firefox cases on VM machine and its throwing below error.**
```

---

```
    **Error Message**
```

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:50352/

### TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**I am adding few code below where issue is throwing issue**
**Stacktrace**

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(String geckoDriverDirectory, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at MPAutomation.Driver.Initialize(String browser) in D:\Workspace.Automation\MPproject\MPAutomation\Utility\Driver.cs:line 79
# code on this line : Instance = new FirefoxDriver(service.FirefoxBinaryPath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));  
  at MPAutomation.BaseTest.Init() in D:\Workspace.Automation\MPproject\MPAutomation\Utils\BaseTest.cs:line 54
  #code here :  LoginPage.GoTo(Settings.BrowserType); # I am passing "Firefox"
--TearDown
   at MPAutomation.Driver.Close() in D:\Workspace.Automation\MPproject\MPAutomation\Utility\Driver.cs:line 117
   # Instance.Close();
   at MPAutomation.BaseTest.Cleanup() in D:\Workspace.Automation\MPproject\MPAutomation\Utils\BaseTest.cs:line 97


---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**firefox implemnetation looks like this in Driver.cs**
     - I tried with various version of Firefox too but none is working on VM

```
else if(browser.Equals(Constant.Firefox))                           {
    // driver init from here 
                            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(DrivePath);
                            service.FirefoxBinaryPath = DrivePath;
                            var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                            profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
                            var options = new FirefoxOptions();
                            options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
                            options.Profile = profile;                
                            Instance = new FirefoxDriver(service.FirefoxBinaryPath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                            Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

                            Utility.Logger.Write("***** Firefox Browser has been initialized now  *********");
                           }

           --------------------------------
    5. We have one certificate for firefox and which has already been taken care locally and on VM 

    6. I am not sure why automation is not able to start firefox on VM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we got the solution of this issue.

We need to set up "sandbox level" for firefox on VM.

profile.setPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/466

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Sandbox